# "Created them flawless/flawlessly"

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

> He created them **flawless**.
>
> He created them **flawlessly**.

If *flawlessly* is correct, what is it an adverb of?

Answer (score 24):

Both are correct, but they mean different things. "He created them flawless" means that the creations were without a flaw, and "he created them flawlessly" means the act of creating them was performed without flaws.

Comment: For example, if he made a mistake but then fixed it, his creation could be *flawless*, but the creation was not done *flawlessly*.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if he designed them wrong intentionally, he could execute the design flawlessly to create things that are not flawless.

Comment: @David Schwartz and jprete - good examples!

Answer (score 4):

"Flawless" is an adjective which must modify a noun, and "flawlessly" is an adverb which must modify the verb. So in the sentences you gave:

> He created them flawless

Here "flawless" modifies "them", as in, they were flawless after he created them.

> He created them flawlessly

Here "flawlessly" can only modify "created", so the act of creation was flawless.

It's a matter of definition whether a flawless act of creation results in a flawless created object.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers have explained the difference well. In grammatical terms, *He created them flawless* is on the pattern Subject-Verb-Object-Complement, whereas *He created them flawlessly* is on the pattern Subject-Verb-Object-Adverbial.